# loop with time math is incorrectly showing AM/PM

Tags: php

In this case `hours_start` will be 08:00:00 and `hours_end` will be 14:00:00

here's the code i'm using to generate a list of 30 minute time slots between start and end

```
while($row = $q->fetch()){
    $hours = $row['hours_end'] - $row['hours_start']; //amount of hours working in day
    for($i = 0; $i < $hours * 2; $i++){ // double hours for 30 minute increments
        $minutes_to_add = 1800 * $i; // add 30 - 60 - 90 etc.
        $timeslot = date('h:i:s', strtotime($row['hours_start'])+$minutes_to_add);
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>" . date('h:i A', strtotime($timeslot)) . "</td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

this is producing:

```
08:00 AM
08:30 AM
09:00 AM
09:30 AM
10:00 AM
10:30 AM
11:00 AM
11:30 AM
12:00 PM
12:30 PM
01:00 AM
01:30 AM
```

as you can see, it is functioning as (i) expected  until it gets to (what should be) 1 PM then it switches back to AM. not sure whats going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you are setting `$timeslot` using `h` which is only a 12 hour format without appending `am` or `pm`. Then taking that 12 hour format and running it through `strtotime` which expects 24 hour format if am or pm is not present. Hence anything after 12 becomes am again.

You need to use:

```
$timeslot = date('H:i:s', strtotime($row['hours_start'])+$minutes_to_add);
```

OR

```
$timeslot = date('h:i:s a', strtotime($row['hours_start'])+$minutes_to_add);
```

Comment: Figures my frustration comes down to a capital letter! Thank you for the explanation too instead of just the fix! Cheers

Comment: No problem, sometimes its the little things that get us. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is using `h` instead of `H`. The lowercase `h` is [12 hour format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Use a capital `H` instead for 24 hours.

```
date('H:i A', strtotime($timeslot))
```